# File.Copy prevents File.WriteAllText - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#

I have a loop that

- deletes a text file called "delete_me" (success)
- renames a new file `fileName` to "delete_me" (success)

...and then I'm trying to append a string to that newly renamed file, but I can't...

`The process cannot access the file 'delete_me.txt' because it is being used by another process.`

```
    File.Delete("delete_me.txt");
    File.Copy(fileName, "delete_me.txt");
    File.WriteAllText("delete_me.txt", "some string");
```

I know there's some `Dispose()` and `Close()` methods that can hang on the back of `File.Create()` but this doesn't seem to apply to `File.Copy()` ??

Any ideas?

I tried `GC.Collect()` but still get the same error.

Comment: My guess would be that antivirus is still holding on to the file.

Comment: I saw that as an answer on some related questions, but surely renaming an existing file with `copy` wouldn't cause AV to kick off?!

Comment: It does, favor File.Rename.  And do consider that this is quite unnecessary, File.WriteAllText() already overwrites the content of a file.

Comment: I have a question. Why are you deleting the file? Why are you copying something into the file? The final WriteAllText will overwrite the file with new content, the copy and delete is quite unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry yes, this was meant to be `AppendAllText()`. I was deleting the `delete_me.txt` file before renaming a new file to that same name - it HAS to be that name for another process to use it.

Comment: I've actually got round it, it seems, by reordering to `File.AppendAllText(fileName, "some string");` then using `File.Copy(fileName, "delete_me.txt");` - no errors at all this way round but it does mean editing the original file which is not what I wanted to do. I guess I could `Copy` and then `Rename` the Copy?!!?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=net-5.0)

```
public static void Copy (string sourceFileName, string destFileName);
```

`sourceFileName` The file to copy.

`destFileName` The name of the destination file. This **cannot** be a directory or an existing file.

Comment: Which is covered by the line directly above it: `File.Delete("delete_me.txt");`...